# How to write an output which is longer than the maximum LRECL in COBOL?

Tags: cobol, jcl

Have you ever worked on VBS or FBS files with more than the maximum LRECL in COBOL?
I want to edit LOB (Large Object) records which are much longer than 32760, write them into files, and transfer them to an Unix server.
If you already have experience, it would be nice if you could give me some tips for processing.

Answer (score 3):

Here is material on the considerations of [Spanned records in COBOL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6SG3_4.2.0/com.ibm.entcobol.doc_4.2/PGandLR/tasks/tpqsm09.htm)

> You can code RECORDING MODE S for spanned records in QSAM files that
>   are assigned to magnetic tape or to direct access devices. Do not
>   request spanned records for files in the HFS. You can omit the
>   RECORDING MODE clause. The compiler determines the recording mode to
>   be S if the maximum record length (in bytes) plus 4 is greater than
>   the block size set in the BLOCK CONTAINS clause.
>
> For files with format S in your program, the compiler determines the
>   maximum record length with the same rules as are used for format V.
>   The length is based on your usage of the RECORD clause.
>
> When creating files that contain format-S records and a record is
>   larger than the remaining space in a block, COBOL writes a segment of
>   the record to fill the block. The rest of the record is stored in the
>   next block or blocks depending on its length. COBOL supports QSAM
>   spanned records up to 32,760 bytes in length.
>
> When retrieving files that have format-S records, a program can
>   retrieve only complete records.

Here is an [explanation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.4.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r4.idad400/xlmo.htm) of storing records that are longer than 32,760 bytes.  Segmented records are not supported via ISPF Edit.  They are kind of an odd beast.

Comment: Memories of Doug Arter, Matt! 

Comment: Ray, do you recall when IBM added VBS support in COBOL?  IIRC back in the day VB was tabooo (ISAM was the player back then) at least back in 1982 ... egad I’m getting old.

Answer (score 2):

You can call C runtime routines from COBOL (or other LE-conforming languages).

```
[...]

   Working-Storage Section.
   01  CONSTANTS.
       05  WS-FILE-OPTN            PIC X(003) VALUE Z'rb'.

   01  WORK-AREAS.
       05  WS-FILE                 POINTER VALUE NULL.
       05  WS-FILE-NM              PIC X(255).

[...]

   Procedure Division.
   
[...]

       CALL 'FOPEN' USING
         BY REFERENCE WS-FILE-NM
         BY REFERENCE WS-FILE-OPTN
         RETURNING WS-FILE
       END-CALL
       IF WS-FILE = NULL
         [error handling, maybe call perror()]
       END-IF
```

This way you can delegate the I/O to the C runtime and do the rest of your logic in COBOL.

Consult the [C runtime library reference](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=reference-library-functions) for documentation on required parameters to your chosen I/O functions.